# Throwing an error when initializing an object

Tags: c++, object

Let's say that when initializing a pet class, I wanted to exclude or disallow dogs or cats as species. What would be the proper way to throw an invalid_argument exception?

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <stdexcept>
using std:: invalid_argument;

struct Pet {
  const string name;
  long age = 0;
  const string species;

  //Pet()= default;
  Pet(): name("CrashDown"),age(0),species("ferret") {};
  Pet(const string & the_name, const string & the_species): name(the_name),   age(0),
  species(the_species) {};
 };
```

Comment: You could use templates if the species were a type. That seems like the most idiomatic approach. Otherwise throw in the ctor body using a normal if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pet(const string & the_name, const string & the_species):      name(the_name), species(the_species), age(0)
  {
  if (species == "cats" || species == "dogs")
    throw std::invalid_argument( "received negative value" );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd do this if you have a specific set of species in mind is to use an enumeration for the species:

```
enum class Species {
  horse,
  lizard,
  human
};
```

then make your class's species of type `Species`. This will limit the things passed into the constructor to "approved" species (i.e., the ones you've included in the `enum`). This will only work if you have a finite (and exhaustive) list of species.

If you want the species to be non-exhaustive, you might want to have a `Species` base class and make the concrete species subclasses. Then you can limit specific types using templates, which would be a compilation error instead of an exception -- much more preferable!

If you don't like any of these options, you can go with the most rigid and error-prone way which is just checking for string equality in the constructor body and throwing in the case that you get a cat, a dog, or any other undesirable species.

Comment: Well, don't give up regarding the monkeys ;-)

Comment: But better don't write answers for questions you already close voted for (as it discloses now).

Comment: Note that it _does_ have to be an `enum class`, not just `enum` which can take any numeric value even those unenumerated (and thus you'd be back to having to validate it yourself)